# How to build wxWidgets with Visual C++

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

I followed along with the [instructions](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/plat_msw_install.html) for building wxWidgets on windows. I opened up a VS2019 command prompt and ran this build command and it finished successfully.

```
nmake /f makefile.vc BUILD=debug TARGET_CPU=X64
```

Trying to use this in another project hasn't been going as good. I copied the [minimal sample](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_helloworld.html) program and while it compiles, I get ~330 link errors (LNK2019+LNK2001).

These are my project settings:

- Include paths: {wxdir}\include, {wxdir}\lib\vc_x64_lib\mswd
- Lib paths: {wxdir}\lib\vc_x64_lib
- Linker inputs (these are all the libs that were created): `wxbase31ud.lib;wxbase31ud_net.lib;wxbase31ud_xml.lib;wxexpatd.lib;wxjpegd.lib;wxmsw31ud_adv.lib;wxmsw31ud_aui.lib;wxmsw31ud_core.lib;wxmsw31ud_gl.lib;wxmsw31ud_html.lib;wxmsw31ud_media.lib;wxmsw31ud_propgrid.lib;wxmsw31ud_qa.lib;wxmsw31ud_ribbon.lib;wxmsw31ud_richtext.lib;wxmsw31ud_stc.lib;wxmsw31ud_webview.lib;wxmsw31ud_xrc.lib;wxpngd.lib;wxregexud.lib;wxscintillad.lib;wxtiffd.lib;wxzlibd.lib`
- Global defines: `WIN32;_DEBUG;_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE=1;_CRT_NON_CONFORMING_SWPRINTFS=1;_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1;__WXMSW__;_UNICODE;_WINDOWS;NOPCH;`

Changing the linker inputs has no effect on the errors at all, even when I remove everything. So I think I must be missing some crucial part of the set up process.

Here are the first 5 of the link errors in case it helps:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: static struct wxEventTable const wxFrame::sm_eventTable" (?sm_eventTable@wxFrame@@1UwxEventTable@@B)

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int const wxEVT_NULL" (?wxEVT_NULL@@3HB)

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class wxEventTypeTag<class wxCommandEvent> const wxEVT_MENU" (?wxEVT_MENU@@3V?$wxEventTypeTag@VwxCommandEvent@@@@B)

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: static class wxAppConsole * (__cdecl* wxAppConsoleBase::ms_appInitFn)(void)" (?ms_appInitFn@wxAppConsoleBase@@1P6APAVwxAppConsole@@XZA)

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void (__cdecl* wxTheAssertHandler)(class wxString const &,int,class wxString const &,class wxString const &,class wxString const &)" (?wxTheAssertHandler@@3P6AXABVwxString@@H000@ZA)
```

Edit: After inspecting some .lib files with dumpbin.exe I found out they are 32-bit. But I specified "TARGET_CPU=X64" in my nmake command. And the output lib folder was called "vc_x64_lib". Is there some other way of specifying x64 that I'm not aware of?

Edit 2: After using the 'x64 Native Tools' command prompt instead, nmake generated 64-bit libs. This had no effect on the link errors...

Comment: Use the x64 command prompt in the start menu to get started.

Comment: @DNg, can you go to wxWidgets \samples\minimal and build the minimal sample with exact same command you used to build the library (from the mavc command prompt)? If that builds fine - note what options are used for building and linking and try to use it in your project. (I presume you are building from msvc and not command prompt).

Comment: @HansPassant - that worked to create 64-bit libs but the link errors persist

Comment: @DNg, Please post build log. Also, I presume you tried to build from the wxWidgets\samples\minimal directory and not from the copy you made...

Comment: @Igor - I followed your advice and noticed the linker inputs were different. I copied over the list and that got it going, thank you! I was thrown off by missing symbols that looked like they should've been in the base lib.

Answer (score 0):

The simples solution is to install wxWidgets via vcpkg. I have done it today. You can then create a C++ - project (subsystem: Windows and not Console).